# How to keep Firebase in sync with another database

Tags: database, firebase

We need to keep our `Firebase` data in sync with other `databases` for `full-text search` (in `ElasticSearch`) and other kinds of queries that `Firebase` doesn't easily support.

This needs to be as close to real-time as possible, we can't just export a nightly dump of the `Firebase JSON` or anything like that, aside from the fact that this will get rather large.

My initial thought was to run a `Node.js` client which listens to `child_changed`, `child_added`, `child_removed` etc... events of all the main lists, but this could get a bit unweildy and would it be a reliable way of syncing if the client re-connects after a period of time?

My next thought was to maintain a list of "items changed" events and write to that every time an item is created/updated, similar to the [Firebase work queue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-work-queue) example. The queue could contain the full path to the data which has changed and the worker just consumes that and updates the local database accordingly.

The problem here is every bit of code which makes updates has to remember to write to this queue otherwise the two systems will get out of sync. Some proxy code shouldn't be too hard to write though.

Has anyone else done anything similar with any success?

Comment: I think your proxy idea makes the most sense. We've definitely seen cases where people have run node.js processes that store timestamps of the last time they wrote data. If the process crashes, you can do an initial import by looking at the last timestamp you wrote.

Comment: @rlivsey Did you come up with a solution? I need to solve the same problem and I was thinking about using Elastic Search. Any information on your experience would be appreciated.

Comment: We resolved this issue, but in our case, the setup is different - we live happily with two databases, each for a different purpose.    
We have MongoDB (*authoritative store*) and Firebase (*real-time store*),  which are **not** identical, each holds the data it requires. Not all real-time data in Firebase need to be written to the MongoDB.   and the other way around - a lot of non-realtime data isn't on our Mongo.  Only a **fragment** of the data is synced: client --> nodejs --> Mongo + Firebase.    

So I guess the question is - do you really need **all** data synced?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For search queries, you can integrate directly with ElasticSearch; there is no need to sync with a secondary database. Firebase has a [blog post about integrating](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-01-02-queries-part-two.html) and a lib, [Flashlight](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight), to make this quick and painless.

Comment: While this is helpful, I decided to write a small piece of code to sync Firebase to Mongo. More info can be found in [this post](https://medium.com/@ariklevliber/querying-firebase-through-mongo-412a824ca4dd#.bp4vz7rkx)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the [logstash-input-firebase](https://github.com/consulthys/logstash-input-firebase) Logstash plugin in order to listen to changes in your Firebase real-time database(s) and forward the data in real-time to Elasticsearch using an `elasticsearch` output.

Comment: can you please add instructions how to install the plugin into logstash ?