# Saving and/or Querying User Display Names in Firebase using caseInSensitive?

Tags: swift, firebase, case-insensitive, querying

I'm moving my project over to Firebase from Swift.  Firebase user's don't have usernames but I'm allowing them to save a display name which works more like a attribute than an actual object.  How can I get users to query for other users/"friends" using case in sensitive text?

Comment: Firebase doesn't have built-in full-text search capabilities. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853908/how-to-keep-firebase-in-sync-with-another-database, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867185/searching-in-firebase-without-server-side-code, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559191/firebase-and-indexing-search and https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-01-02-queries-part-two.html

Comment: You can't move a project from Swift, a programming language to Firebase, a JSON data store, unless you are referring to how your data is stored (MySQL? CoreData?).

Comment: I'm sorry, Yes I'm moving to Firebase from Parse using Swift programming. If you're the same user that supplied the below answer - It works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily accomplish this task. We don't know how your current data is structured but here's an example

```
users
  user_id_0
    dsplay_name: "Smokey"
    lower_case_name: "smokey"
  user_id_1
    display_name: "Bandit"
    lower_case_name: "bandit"
```

When you create a user in Firebase, create a node in the /users node with their uid as the node name, and then display_name and lower_case_name as children

When you write your data to the users node, just lower case the display name when you are writing to the lower_case_name child:

```
let lowerCaseString = displayNameString.lowercaseString
let userRef = the users uid

let userData = ["display_name": "Bandit", "lower_case_name": lowerCaseString]
userRef.setValue(userData)
```

Then you query on the lower_case_name child using a lower case string.

```
ref.queryOrderedByChild("lower_case_name").queryEqualToValue("bandit")
   .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
}
```