# Can i send data from firebase to my website?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Can I send data from firebase to my website? I am interested in storing data of android app to the firebase, then retrieve the data in my website. Is this possible to do?

Comment: i think your answer is here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853908/how-to-keep-firebase-in-sync-with-another-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can connect an Web app and an Android app to the same Firebase project and then share the same database, cloud storage, and other resources between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the data using javascript, then you'd need to create the logic to deal with that info.

The proccess is quite similar to Android: you get the app info from your firebase app and you can use very similar methods to retrieve the data.

This process is way to long to describe here but you can refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?hl=pt-br to get started.